# MySQL - Why is my query returning just one row instead of three?

Tags: mysql

I've got 3 entries in the `messages` table of a MySQL database where the receiver's id is the integer 291. My query should select these three entries and left join the name and gavatar of the receiver from the accounts table;

```
SELECT
m.audiourl, 
m.receiver, 
m.audioid, 
m.sender,   
ac.gavatar, 
ac.name 
FROM messages m 
LEFT JOIN accounts ac ON ac.id = m.sender
WHERE m.receiver = 291
```

Here's the messages table;

[image: Messages Table]

But instead of returning three rows of JSON data, it's returning only the first row. IE;

```
{"audiourl":"87-message-291-4.m4a","receiver":291,"audioid":4,"sender":87,"gavatar":"87-user.jpg","name":"GroovyGrrl"}
```

It should look like this;

```
[{
"audiourl":"87-message-291-4.m4a","receiver":291,"audioid":4,"sender":87,"gavatar":"87-user.jpg","name":"GroovyGrrl",
"audiourl":"87-message-291-5.m4a","receiver":291,"audioid":4,"sender":87,"gavatar":"87-user.jpg","name":"GroovyGrrl",
"audiourl":"87-message-291-6.m4a","receiver":291,"audioid":4,"sender":87,"gavatar":"87-user.jpg","name":"GroovyGrrl"
}]
```

What's wrong with my query?

Comment: Either your query is producing unexpected results - in this case you should share sample data from both tables not just expected results. Or your node.js code retrieves the results incorrectly - in this case you need to share how you fetch the rows in node.js. First you must determine which is the case.

Comment: Have you run your query directly in mysql? If so, what was the output? If not, then run it and check the output.

Comment: Please share more details. As MySQL itself does not return stuff JSON encoded, have you checked your application for problems?

Comment: Thanks Shadow! Yes the query runs fine directly in mysql, so the problem is at the NodeJS or Flutter application end. I guess I should investigate those. I'll check nodejs with Postman

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the troubleshooting advice I received here in the comments I learned that the problem was with the NodeJS not the MySQL query.

I was using this to collect the results of the query;

```
const audiourl = row_a[0].audiourl;
const receiver = row_a[0].receiver;
const audioid = row_a[0].audioid;
const sender = row_a[0].sender;
const gavatar = row_a[0].gavatar;
const name = row_a[0].name;
const timestamp = row_a[0].timestamp;
```

With this to return the JSON;

```
  res.json({
   "audiourl": audiourl,
   "receiver": receiver,
   "audioid": audioid,
   "sender": sender,
   "gavatar": gavatar,
   "name": name,
   "timestamp": timestamp     
    });
```

But instead I should have skipped all the variables and simply done this;

```
  res.json(row_a)
```

The "0" in `row_a[0]` was returning just the first row.